# DSA_Sort not in libcomctl32.a: undefined reference to __imp_DSA_Sort

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64

Compiling a test application using `GoogleMock` with mingw 64.
Even though I link with `comctl32` I get this error::

```
In function `DSA_Sort(_DSA*, int (*)(void const*, void const*, long long), long long)':
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/commctrl.h:5350: undefined reference to `__imp_DSA_Sort'
```

Without linking to `comctl32` additional `__imp_DSA_XXX()` are undefined, like `__imp_DSA_DestroyCallback()`.
`objdump libcomctl32.a -t` does not show `DSA_Sort()`, but it shows `DSA_DestroyCallback`.

`V6.0.0` sources comctl32.def does not show `DSA_Sort()`. It is in `commctrl.def` and in `coredll.def`, though, and of course `commctrl.h`.

Is the missing `DSA_sort()` in `libcomctl32.a` a bug of mingw-w64
or is this function in some other `libxxx.a` file? Which one?
If it is a bug, how should one report it?

Answer (score 0):

### Comctl32.dll

```
ld \Windows\System32\comctl32.dll --output-def=comctl32.def
```

does not show a `DSA_Sort()`, although the documentation says it should be there.

### DSA_Sort

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dpa_dsa/nf-dpa_dsa-dsa_sort

Lib: ComCtl32.dll

```
BOOL DSA_Sort(
  HDSA         pdsa,
  PFNDACOMPARE pfnCompare,
  LPARAM       lParam
);
```

### dsa_dsa.h

```
\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\dpa_dsa.h
```

defines `DSA_Sort()` the same way MinGW `commctrl.h` does.

But `dpa_dsa.h` has `#include "dpa_dsa.inl"` if `ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED` is defined,
which MinGW does not support (https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/feature-requests/44/).

```
\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\dpa_dsa.inl
```

contains:

```
#define DSA_Sort IsolationAwareDSA_Sort
```

and has this inline implementation:

```
ISOLATION_AWARE_INLINE BOOL IsolationAwarePrivatenCv IsolationAwareDSA_Sort(_Inout_ HDSA pdsa,_In_ PFNDACOMPARE pfnCompare,_In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    BOOL fResult = FALSE;
    typedef BOOL (WINAPI* PFN)(_Inout_ HDSA pdsa,_In_ PFNDACOMPARE pfnCompare,_In_ LPARAM lParam);
    static PFN s_pfn;
    PFN __IsolationAware_pfn = s_pfn;
    ULONG_PTR ulpCookie = 0;
    const BOOL fActivateActCtxSuccess =
        IsolationAwarePrivateT_SAbnPgpgk ||
        IsolationAwarePrivateT_SqbjaYRiRY ||
        IsolationAwarePrivatenPgViNgRzlnPgpgk(&ulpCookie);
    if (!fActivateActCtxSuccess)
        return fResult;
    __try
    {
        if (__IsolationAware_pfn == NULL)
        {
            __IsolationAware_pfn = (PFN) Dpa_dsaIsolationAwarePrivatetRgCebPnQQeRff_pbZPgYQP_QYY("DSA_Sort");
            if (__IsolationAware_pfn == NULL)
                __leave;
            s_pfn = __IsolationAware_pfn;
        }
        fResult = __IsolationAware_pfn(pdsa,pfnCompare,lParam);
    }
    __finally
    {
        if (!IsolationAwarePrivateT_SAbnPgpgk
         || !IsolationAwarePrivateT_SqbjaYRiRY
        )
        {
            const BOOL fPreserveLastError = (fResult == FALSE);
            const DWORD dwLastError = fPreserveLastError ? GetLastError() : NO_ERROR;
            (void)IsolationAwareDeactivateActCtx(0, ulpCookie);
            if (fPreserveLastError)
                SetLastError(dwLastError);
        }
    }
    return fResult;
}
```

With

```
#if !ISOLATION_AWARE_USE_STATIC_LIBRARY
FARPROC IsolationAwarePrivatenCv Dpa_dsaIsolationAwarePrivatetRgCebPnQQeRff_pbZPgYQP_QYY(LPCSTR pszProcName);
#endif /* ISOLATION_AWARE_USE_STATIC_LIBRARY */
```

It seems like Windows API is explicity hiding this function from MinGW.

See also:
https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/comctl32/api/da/dsa/index.htm